# App crashes when getting Notes from AddressBook iphone

Tags: iphone, memory, crash, addressbook

Here is my code to get Notes from AddressBook.

```
 +(NSString*)getNote:(ABRecordRef)record {

  return ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonNoteProperty);
}
```

But in above implementation I have memory leak. So to remove memory leak I wrote following code

```
    +(NSString*)getNote:(ABRecordRef)record {

    NSString *tempNotes = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonNoteProperty);
    NSString *notes = [NSString stringWithString:tempNotes];
    [tempNotes release];
    return notes;

}
```

If I write above code my app crashes. Whats going wrong? Thanks.

UPDATE: I call this method as follows :

```
notes = [AddreesBook getNote:record];
```

where notes is my ivar & I am releasing it in dealloc method.

Comment: What does it say when it crashes?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first implementation violates the ownership rule:

[Memory Management Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)

Which is to say, the API call you're using contains "Copy", but you're treating it like an autoreleased object.

Given that you're returning an autoreleased object in your revised implementation, I suspect you're not retaining your returned note string. You'll be able to tell for sure if this is the case if when running under a debugger your app crashes in `NSPopAutoreleasePool()`.

A simple test would be to send `-retain` to the note object you get back and see if the crash goes away:

```
NSString    *note = [ MyAddressBook getNote: abRecord ];

[ note retain ];
/* ... use note ... */

/* we retained the object, we must also release it when done with it. */
[ note release ];
```

Comment: Thanks for info. I will check your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `record` parameter is correctly set, the following should return an autoreleased NSString.

```
+ (NSString *)getNote:(ABRecordRef)record {
    return [(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonNoteProperty) autorelease];
}
```

However, I'm not currently seeing why your current version of `getNote` isn't working.